Is it possible to push 1 GB commit to git repository
I want to create easily updatable backup of my document files. Currently, it's of 1 GB size. I tried pushing commit with this, but always ended up:

error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I think this isn't possible with git. If this is true, could you tell me what technology I should use?

Maybe look at Git Large File Storage

https://medium.com/swlh/everything-you-need-to-know-to-resolve-the-git-push-rpc-error-1a865fd1ebea

Git isn't suitable for backing up files. Been there, done that, failed miserably. Consider a proper backup solution or file synchronization facility.

".....could you tell me what technology I should use?"

Git doesn't have a limit. Your hosting service provider probably has a limit.

I thought it was asking for suggestions, (which is a reason to close), but it is actually a duplicate, see: Github - unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet

Git doesn't care about the size. But plain Git is not good at tracking binary files. Say you have a 1GB file, flip one bit, create a new commit. Worst case: your repository is now 2GB in size.
